# How do I use an older version of SpringBoot on a project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Recently I bought a course on Udemy of Java SpringBoot, and it requires the 2.3.4 version, but this version is not available anymore to create a project. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2021.2.1.

I tried changing the pom.xml file but it didn't work out, as I got the error: `"Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.3.4 in central"`.

So far, I tried changing the IDE for SpringToolSuite4 and asking for Maven to update the project and running `mvn -U clean install`, but still didn't work.

Is there anything I can do to fix this ?

Comment: try 2.3.4.RELEASE, spring boot older versions had RELEASE with their version name.

Comment: Note that you can _usually_ use any newer 2.x version without much problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot Versions before 2.4.X have had been version definition like `2.3.4.RELEASE` ...  instead of `2.3.4.`
https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent